# Can't search in Windows 10 start menu and can't open settings

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, bug

If I open start menu and type something, nothing happens, as if I was not pressing any keys. My mouse becomes the spinner though as if it's thinking. If I turn the search box on and try and type in it, it goes unfocused as if it crashed and rebooted.

Trying to open settings any way results in it popping up, then closing immediately. I got a really cryptic error at one point that made it sound like the settings menu wasn't installed. No idea what I did to get the error, can't reproduce.

I tried running:

```
"Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}"
```

But it threw a lot of errors saying that the package could not be registered.

running "sfc /scannow" as admin returns:

```
Beginning system scan. This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.

Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
```

The search functionality briefly returned earlier today, but after restarting my computer to install a windows update, it has ceased functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the initial repair steps have failed, run a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

If Repair fails (it might because of all the errors), back up your data and reinstall Windows.

Here is a screen shot of the relevant page from the link above.

[image]

Comment: Do I want to create an installation media? As in download the media tool?

Comment: You can try running the repair directly from the link, or, you can download the ISO to a USB Key and then with Windows 10 running, open the USB folder and run Setup. That launches the Repair. I have don numerous repairs before.

Comment: I dont see an option for repair on that page

Comment: When you open the download page, choose the second link (the top link is to upgrade) and run the second link. I will edit my answer in a bit.

Comment: Alright. In the wizard I just downloaded, it is asking if I want to "upgrade" or make a "install media". Which do I want?

Comment: Make the install media and run Setup from it. I showed the page in my answer